# Simple numerical progression

Tags: probability

a) Every $5$ mins, a number will either go low ($-1$) or stay the same ($-0$). what is the chance of the number $4$ being $2$ after $20$ mins?

I can solve question "a" by simply drawing the question out. I want to know the equation behind the question.

b) Refer to Question "a)"
If a person can add $+1$ at every $n$ minutes, what is the best interval to add $+1$ to maintain original number $4$ for longest?

For example) $+\frac{1}{5}$ mins, $+\frac{1}{10}$mins.

I will appreciate it with detail explanation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a, you have four incidents.  You need two of them to be -1 and two to be zero.  Presumably (the question does not say) the chance of each is $\frac 12$, so you are asking the chance of two heads in four flips of a coin.  Look up the binomial distribution.

b is badly stated.  I would guess it means you start at 4, you do the 0/-1 thing every 5 minutes and get to add 1 however often you want.  You then count how many times you have 4.  Clearly on average you get a -1 every 10 minutes so you want to add 1 every 10 minutes.